# Equivalence relation ( check )

Tags: logic

$Let X=\left\{ 1,2,3...16\right\} $. Is that true , that $xRy \Leftrightarrow 4| x^{2}+ y^{2}$ is an equivalence relation?

$4| x^{2}- x^{2} = 4|0$ reflexivity  <- I found this example on the internet. I do not understand why that is.
Please about a comment .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different examples going on here.  The example you asked in your first sentence is whether or not $x\mathcal{R}y\iff 4\mid x^2\color{red}{+}y^2$ is an equivalence relation over $X$.  Remember that an equivalence relation must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  In particular, it must be reflexive meaning that for any $x\in X$ it must be true that $x\mathcal{R}x$.  Remember back to quintessential examples of equivalence relations, like $=$.  It should always be true that $x=x$.

Now... for your specific example, is it true that $1\mathcal{R}1$?

> Is $1^2+1^2$ a multiple of $4$?

What does this imply?

---

Later in your question, you reference a completely different example, namely the other relation, I'll call $\mathcal{T}$ where $x\mathcal{T}y\iff 4\mid x^2\color{red}{-}y^2$.  In this example it actually is reflexive since for any choice of $x$ one has $x^2-x^2=0=0\cdot4$ which is indeed a multiple of $4$ implying that $x\mathcal{T}x$ for any choice of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

To see if it is an equivalence relation, you need to check reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.  A relation $R$ is reflexive if $\forall x (xRx)$.  Your example is wrong in that you should be checking whether $4|x^2+x^2$.  We first check $x=1$ and ask if $4|1^2+1^2$ and find it does not.  Therefore $1 \not R 1$ and the relation is not reflexive.  I believe the typo is in the definition of the relation.  It should be $xRy \Leftrightarrow 4| x^{2}- y^{2}$, which would make the example conform to the definition.  Now the relation is reflexive because $4|0$